# Can't connect to mongo db on a debian VM from Windows host

Tags: node.js, windows, mongodb, virtual-machine, econnrefused

I am doing doing a project where I have a mongo database on a debian VM 9.8.0 (with last virtualbox version).
I have a nodejs app on my computer (Windows 10) and I want to connect this application to my mongo database. 
I tried a lot of things but still get the same error : 
Error : connect ECONNREFUSED :217017

- I tried to disable firewall on my computer and on the VM
- I tried all VM network conf possible (currently on private host network)
- I can ping my VM from my computer and from my computer to the VM
- The application is working with a mongo database in local
- Probably a bad config somewhere, the code seems correct
- The mongod service is running with the command : sudo service mongod start
- I can see that mongod is in LISTENING state by using lsof -i

nodejs server : (launched with "node server.js" command)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//****** MONGODB *******/
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const urlMongo = 'mongodb://192.168.56.101:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'projet';

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(urlMongo);
```

error :

```sh
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.56.101:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
  errn... == null
    at D:\Basile\Master Informatique\BDD\Projet\server.js:134:20
    at err (D:\Basile\Master Informatique\BDD\Projet\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:411:14)
    at executeCallback (D:\Basile\Master Informatique\BDD\Projet\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:401:25)
    at err (D:\Basile\Master Informatique\BDD\Projet\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:285:21)
    at connectCallback (D:\Basile\Master Informatique\BDD\Projet\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:265:5)
    at server.connect (D:\Basile\Master Informatique\BDD\Projet\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:353:14)
    at Server.<anonymous> (D:\Basile\Master Informatique\BDD\Projet\node_modules\mongodb\lib\topologies\server.js:237:11)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Pool.<anonymous> (D:\Basile\Master Informatique\BDD\Projet\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:452:12)
```

Since the application is running with a local mongo db, I do not understand why it is not running well with my VM.

Comment: You could be running something currently on this port are you?  Make sure your MongoDB instance is running using mongod.

Comment: I checked that nothing was already running on this port and I'm sure that mongod is on. I am running mongod in a ssh session and I can see that the service is here by using lsof -i :(

Comment: Just to be sure, I did a netcat -a in my cmd and I saw that 127.0.0.1:27017 was in LISTENING state, does that mean that the port is already used ?

Comment: A listening state for a port just means it is waiting for a connection. You ca try : ps -elf | grep mongo to see if its running. Alternativley please make sure that MongoDB is started sudo service mongod start